# ASP.NET WebApi POST не приходит на сервер IIS. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: веб-программирование, post, iis, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект на ASP.NET WebApi. Есть метод, принимающий POST запрос, и в качестве параметра выступает созданная мною модель типа TestModel. Высылаю на локалку - всё работает - на сервере - нет. Не приходит объект модели. На GET всё работает без проблем. Сразу же в голове возникает решение - разрешить POST на сервере IIS. Ну тогда подскажите где это делается. CORS разрешены. Это не первый раз когда не работает POST на IIS.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(TestModel test)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(test.email);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не приходит модель (приходит null), или вообще не вызывается Login?

Comment: Вызывается, но приходит null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том что на Windows Server на IIS был не установлен толи модуль, толи компонент, отвечающий за безопасность. Если не ошибаюсь назывался он IIS Security.