# ASP.NET CORE WebApi POST не приходит на сервер IIS. Запрос срабатывает, но биндинг null

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, post, asp.net-core

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой как тут: [ASP.NET WebApi POST не приходит на сервер IIS. В чём может быть проблема?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501152/asp-net-webapi-post-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-iis-%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).

На локалке не обрабатываются POST запросы. GET работает изумительно. Через консоль ставил модуль IIS Security (Start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-Security;), но все равно любой POST запрос выдает null данные... Вообще любой (даже когда создаю пустой проект и пишу простое тестовое приложение с нуля и кидаю в него запрос постманом).

Если кто решил похожую проблему - можете подробнее описать как вы установили или настроили IIS Security? (Автор пишет, что у него решилось после установки именно этого).

Пишу в VS2017 проект Web Api в ASP Net Core.

Comment: Сделал простой пример с одним строковым полем. Запрос простой: {"operationName":"verifyAccount"} на контроллере пробовал и [FromBody] и все прочее. Всегда null. Контроллер для теста элементарный: public IActionResult Post(string operationName) { var test = operationName; return Ok();}

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Дело в том, что беру вот ради интереса пустой core проект и делаю простую модель с элементарным контроллером, который принимает эту модель и все равно null. Даже вот шаг за шагом повторил за пользователями на ютубе у которых все биндится. Такое чувство, что локальный IIS сервер не пропускает POST запросы, а как это решить - не знаю...

Comment: меня смущает название метода `Post` можете попробовать дать другое имя и я не вижу атрибута `HttpPost`

Comment: Атрибут был(не вставил сюда). Попробовал сменить имя и добавить роутинг: [HttpPost] [Route("verifyAccount")] public IActionResult verifyAccount(string operationName) { var test = operationName; return Ok();} Запрос контроллером обрабатывается, но переменная operationName опять null.

Comment: можете показать заголовки запроса который уходит на сервер

Comment: Тестовый запрос из Постмана: POST /api/account/verifyAccount HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3875
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3f319e39-3b3f-f9f6-c77b-9bc193eba515

{"operationName":"verifyAccount"}

Comment: возможно дурная затея, но все же: попробуйте изменить `{"operationName":"verifyAccount"}` на `operationName:"verifyAccount"`

Comment: Пробовал. Синтаксис не верный же в таком случае будет. А результат такой же. К слову GET запросы же работают успешно. Проблема лишь с POST

Comment: я же правильно понял что тело запроса в постмане Вы заполняете как: `x-www-form-urlencoded` и там добавляете ключ `operationName` и его значение?

Comment: Если заполнять так, то все принимает. Но у меня основная задача в проекте биндить целый класс, которые клиент передает в формате content-type:application/json и пример данных в запросе будет: {"query":"mutation verifyAccount($verifyPhone: String!, $agentID: String!, $fistName: String!, $lastName: String!) {  verifyAccount(verifyPhone: $verifyPhone, agentID: $agentID, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName)}","variables":{"verifyPhone":"2","agentID":"1","firstName":"3","lastName":"4"},"operationName":"verifyAccount"}

Comment: а вы измените метод на сервере, что бы он принимал экземпляр нужного класса, и передайте с постмана выше указанным способом необходимые ключи-значения. у меня [tag:asp.net-web-api] на клиенте ангуляр. модель выглядит так `let model = {key1: value2, key2: value2};` отправляю так: `$http.post(url,model)` и на сервер все прекрасно доходит

Comment: Так это понятно, проблема в том, что у меня клиент передает только в таком формате, и в MVC или просто Web API - с биндингом нет проблем. А в .net core появились...

Comment: мне кажется Вам стоит переосмыслить вопрос и отредактировать его: привести пример класса, пример данных, что у Вас используется в качестве клиента(хотя это может быть и не обязательно если на клиент вы повлиять не можете)

Comment: Я нашел еще что существует атрибут [Produces("application/json")] но с ним тоже не захотело работать. А насчет примеров - у меня не принимает в application/json обычный пример с ютуба, например: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9iBjM-x5Jc